# How to convert a Java object to key-value string

Tags: java

I have this Java object and I will like to convert it into a key-value string joined by ampersand.

```
private String name;
private int age;
private String address;
private String city;
```

Convert into this key-value string.

```
name=John&age=30&address=12st NW Street&city=New York
```

I have tried Jackson but I dont want a JSON string.
I have tried URIEncoder but I don't need it to be encoded.
Tried looping each property using reflection, but I guess theres a better way.

I have considered toString, but I want something more flexible. Because properties name might change.

Comment: you can achieve this by overriding toString() function.

Comment: You could use Jackson to convert the pojo to a plain map, then basically just concat the entries into a string. Of course that doesn't work for more complex objects and deeper nesting - so maybe you might want to rethink the approach.

Comment: `"name=" + name + "&age=" + age + "&address=" + address + "&city=" + city`

Comment: I've updated the question. Dont want to use toString because property names might change, and I dont want to update on 2 different places.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "I need it to be encoded" ?

Comment: Have you considered using `getDeclaredFields()` from Java reflection and overriding the `toString()` method?

Comment: @cyberbrain missed Don't. corrected.

Comment: There’s no sense in wasting hours trying all those inappropriate methods for something you can write down in three seconds and also adapt to whatever format change in three seconds. The real challenge will be adapting all the other code that uses this class when you really change the name of the property. Which will have the result that you will never change the names of these properties. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI

Comment: @Holger I get your concern. But since I'm using lombok. So im not writting any getter/setter or toString.

Comment: Since you opened this question, you *are* writing the code that produces the string. And implementing it as `"name=" + name + "&age=" + age + "&address=" + address + "&city=" + city` takes a few seconds, is simple *and* efficient. The accepted answer wastes lots of resources, for the questionable benefit of saving you three seconds of typing *if* you ever really change the name of a property. And then, you probably have to drop that code anyway, because it turns out that you have to stay backward compatible to the old string format, regardless of the property’s real name…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the proposition of @Thomas where you can use for example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, String> map = mapper.convertValue(person, Map.class);

String response = map.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> String.format("%s=%s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
```

**Outputs**

```
name=John&age=30&address=12st NW Street&city=New York
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the toString() function to get required format -

```
private String name;
private int age;
private String address;
private String city;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "name=" + name +
            "&age=" + age +
            "&address=" + address +
            "&city=" + city;
}
```

Comment: You can change format here as per your requirement.